# Yum update error and returns system error

Tags: yum, upgrade

[image][image]Error Type: 
Error Value: File contains no section headers.

I don’t understand I did not edit or did anything to that `repos.d` file :(

```
[root@planetery ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, line: 1
' CentOS-Base.repo\n'
[root@planetery ~]#
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of ```/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo```?

Comment: i added the info to main post as an screenshot.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a missing comment from the top of the file. Put a # in front of the very first line that says CentOS-Base.repo, yum should then work fine.

Have you/anyone modified this file?

Comment: Thanks alot now update works. But i never modified it how and when it got modified i have no idea.

Comment: after finishing dependency resolution some error packages are reported. and in the end it was like this {You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
rpmdb: read: 0x7fd74d898708, 4096: Input/output error
error: db3 error(5) from dbcursor->c_get: Input/output error
rpmdb: read: 0x7fd74d898708, 4096: Input/output error
error: db3 error(5) from dbcursor->c_get: Input/output error
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
bluez-4.66-1.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of dbus-bluez-pin-helper}

Comment: Input/output errors are generally not a good sign, this possibly inicates a hardware issue. You could try running a ```yum clean all``` as a first step.

Comment: Can you suggest in general what might be the possible hardware issues cause this??

Comment: Probably a hard disk issue if there are Input/Output errors, but it's not definite. I would suggest starting with ```yum clean all``` and trying the updates again. If not then look at ```dmesg``` to see if there are any indications of hardware problems.

Comment: What actually yum clean all will be doing. Is it safe to do . Will there be any affect on presently working setup of my system

Comment: After trying yum clean all i tried yum update again and saw this You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
rpmdb: read: 0x7fc140952708, 4096: Input/output error
error: db3 error(5) from dbcursor->c_get: Input/output error
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
bluez-4.66-1.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of dbus-bluez-pin-helper

Comment: [root@planetery ~]# yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
rpmdb: read: 0x7f84a8967708, 4096: Input/output error
error: db3 error(5) from dbcursor->c_get: Input/output error
rpmdb: read: 0x7f84a8967708, 4096: Input/output error
error: db3 error(5) from dbcursor->c_get: Input/output error
}

Comment: What does ```dmesg``` show? You might want to put it on a pastebin style website than trying to paste inline.

Comment: showing somekindaend_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 1130448 sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Recovered Error [current] [descriptor]
Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
        72 01 04 1d 00 00 00 0e 09 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 
        00 00 00 00 00 50

Comment: That does look like a potential hard disk problem, I would suggest running an FSCK on this partition. I suggest that you raise a new question for this as it's not a yum error anymore. I believe my answer to your original question solved that problem. I'll be happy to help you on a new question related to the disk issue.